# How to read responseText of ajax returned value

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to catch if my AJAX call returns a 401 exception. Here is my code:

```
error: function(error) {
    var CevapHata = error.responseText.toString();
    var pos=CevapHata.IndexOf("401");
}
```

But when I try to cacth index of 401, there is an error as Object doesn't support this property or method. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive, try

```
 var pos = CevapHata.indexOf("401");
```

with a small "i".

Answer (score 1):

You should use `indexOf` -- with lower `i` char. Here if some additional info you may like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

BTW: MDN is a GREAT source for JS developer. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

Come to think of it, if you're just interested in the status-code of the response you should be able to pull that out of the passed error-object. That would be better practice than searching the response for some string.
It's probably

```
error.status
```

Also, [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) is nice to inspect that kind of stuff, just write

```
console.debug(error);
```

in your handler and you can inspect the object in the console.

Also, you should check out the docs on XMLHttpRequest on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest